# Merge sort implementation a struggle due to way variables are stored

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, merge, mergesort

I have some C++ and Python experience but definitely I have been struggling with this one. I get the concept of merge sort but I don't understand how Python stores the values. I focused on sorting only `[11, 26, 9]` for the sake of dividing this monster into smaller pieces.

To be more concrete, in the output below, what happens after this line:
1 1 2 (i j k) before 2nd while loop? Which loop does Python execute to get to the last line of the attached output? My main confusion is about [11] ending up between 9 and 26. Which loop did cause that?

```
OUTPUT:
[11, 26, 9] left;
[15, 17, 77] right;
[11, 26, 9, 15, 17, 77] myList after dividing by 2;
[11] left;
[26, 9] right;
[11, 26, 9] myList after dividing by 2;
[26] left;
[9] right;
[26, 9] myList after dividing by 2;
[26] left;
[9] right;
[26, 9] myList at zero;
1 length of right;
1 length of left;
0 0 0 (i j k) before if loop;
[9, 9] myList at else;
[26] left before 2nd while loop;
[9] right before 2nd while loop;
0 1 1  (i j k) before 2nd while loop;
[9, 26] myList 2nd while loop i;
[11] left;
[9, 26] right;
[11, 26, 9] myList at zero;
2 length of right;
1 length of left;
0 0 0 (i j k) before if loop;
[9, 26, 9] myList at else;
[11] left;
[9, 26] right;
[9, 26, 9] myList at zero;
2 length of right;
1 length of left;
0 1 1 (i j k) before if loop;
[9, 26, 9] myList at if;
[11] left before 2nd while loop;
[9, 26] right before 2nd while loop;
1 1 2  (i j k) before 2nd while loop;//WHAT HAPPENS HERE NEXT WITH [11]?
[11] left after 2nd while loop j;
[9, 26] right after 2nd while loop j;
[9, 11, 26] myList 2nd while loop j;
```

```
import scipy.io as sio, math as m, numpy as np, sympy as sym, scipy as sp

def mergeSort(myList):
    if len(myList) > 1:
        mid = len(myList) // 2
        left = myList[:mid]
        print(left, "left")
        right = myList[mid:]
        print(right, "right")
        print(myList, "myList after dividing by 2")
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)
        i, j, k = 0, 0, 0
     
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            print(left, "left")
            print(right,"right")
            print(myList, "myList at zero")
            print(len(right), "length of right")
            print(len(left), "length of left")
            print(i, j, k, "(i j k) before if loop")
            # ---------------------------------------------------------------------    
            if left[i] < right[j]:
                print(myList, "myList at if")
                myList[k] = left[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                myList[k] = right[j]
                print(myList, "myList at else")
                j += 1
           
            k += 1
            # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        print(left, "left before 2nd while loop")
        print(right, "right before 2nd while loop")
        print(i, j, k, " (i j k) before 2nd while loop")
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        while i < len(left):
            myList[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
            print(myList, "myList 2nd while loop i")
            
        while j < len(right):
            myList[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
            print(left, "left after 2nd while loop j")
            print(right, "right after 2nd while loop j")
            print(myList, "myList 2nd while loop j")
            
myList = [11,26,9,15,17,77]
mergeSort(myList)
print(myList)
```

Comment: It might be easier to understand if you return a new sorted list instead of changing the incoming list...?

Comment: If interested, I can add an answer showing an optimized top down merge sort in Python, that uses a pair of mutually recursive functions to change the direction of merge based on level of recursion. Note that the Python version is 50 to 100+ times as slow as the same logic in C / C++.

Comment: Well, I am trying to see what actually happens with the code. I know better Python than C++ and it seems more user friendly by showing all the steps for a newbie like me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if i fully understand your question, so please correct me if my answer does not satisfy your question.

When you call your mergeSort() the length is three, so the input is split into left [11] and right [26, 9]. This split does not affect the input myList [11, 26, 9] in any way.

After the internal calls of mergesort left is still [11], but right got changed to [9, 26].

The first while loop then overrides the first value in myList with 9. In the second iteration it overrides the second value of myList with 11. Neither left nor right are affected by this, so they still remain left [11] and right [9, 26]. (i, j, k) is now (1, 1, 2), so the first while-loop ends.

The second while-loop is skipped, so no changes there.

In the third loop the remaining third value of myList is overridden with the value 26 from the second spot in right.

This ends the original call of mySort(...) and outside this call the modified list can be used.

Does this satisfy your question?

P.S.: I know this is not your target, but since python is not an good performing language, try to use built-in functions or libraries, since most of them are compiled in C/C++ and thus much faster than self-implented versions :)

Comment: The asker of the question tried to edit a response. It is entered here:
```Thanks for helping out! Below is my output. I am not sure what really happens after this line: 1 1 2 (i j k) before 2nd while loop. How does Python execute this code that somehow 11 ends between 9 and 26? ```

Like i wrote in the answer, the eleven is already in the second spot after the first while loops completes. You can see what i mean if you move the ```print(myList, "myList at if")``` statement down below the assignment ```myList[k] = left[i]```

Comment: Well, not quite regarding print(myList, "myList at if"). See my original post, the output. I get in that line: [9, 26, 9] myList at if;                                                                 
                                                                                                                          
Anyway, I do appreciate your effort trying to help me out. No question about that!

Comment: Yes, but in the line following that print the eleven gets inserted into the variable ```mylist```
The output you have there contains the state before the if in the whileloop
Thus the output misses the insertion of the eleven